# Passing data row of a GridView into another Web Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am retrieving the SQL data into data grid view now I want particular row data into the other web from, but I am getting null object reference.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

```
public void dgvEmployee_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.Close();
    Update up = new Update();
    up.IdBox.Text = this.dgvEmployee.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(); 
    up.NameBox.Text = this.dgvEmployee.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 
    up.ManagerBox.Text = this.dgvEmployee.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(); 
    up.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you can pass all data as parameter in update constructotor

Comment: Null exception at which line?